# Как вызвать пользователя по firstname в Telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Пишу бота в Телеграме (на Python).
Как сделать так, чтобы он мог вызывать участников беседы по имени?
Допустим, есть пользователь Телеграм с `first_name:'Ivan'`, `last_name:'Ivanov'`, `username:'ivan345'`.
Чтобы обратиться к нему в чате, мне нужно написать его юзернейм `@ivan345`. Как обратится к пользователю по его имени, чтобы `first_name Ivan` был гиперссылкой (без @ и username).
Например, `message.from_user` (id, username или firstname) возвращает как обычный String без гиперссылок на самого пользователя.
Хочу, чтобы бот вызывал пользователей по их `firstname`.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '{first}, {last} @{username}'.format(first=message.from_user.first_name,
                                                                           last=message.from_user.last_name,
                                                                           username=message.from_user.username))
```

Answer (score 1):

Все написали ответы, не соответствующие условию.

Для этого надо сделать ссылку по ID пользователя. По ссылке можно попасть в профиль, только если пользователь состоит в этом чате.

Теперь к техническим деталям:
Нужно сделать вот такую ссылку

```
<a href="tg://user?id=USER_ID">Любой текст</a>
```

Как сделать такую ссылку, чтобы текстом был first_name?

```
mention = f'<a href="tg://user?id={message.from_user.id}">{message.from_user.first_name}</a>'
```

Теперь мы можем вставить mention в наше сообщение, например:

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Привет, {mention}!", parse_mode="HTML")
```

Если планируете использовать parse_mode="markdown", то код mention будет другим:

```
mention = f'[{message.from_user.first_name}](tg://user?id={message.from_user.id})'
```

Готово!

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать конкатенацию

`tb.send_message(message.chat.id, ('Привет, '+message.from_user.first_name))`

или так

`tb.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Привет, {message.from_user.first_name}')`